# Android - java.lang.SecurityException: Spcc API access permission is not granted

Tags: android

I have a small size Android Application in Google Play. I see this error log in crash-reporting tool.

```
stackTrace: java.lang.SecurityException: Spcc API access permission is not granted for uid=10221 pkgName=com.xxx.xxx pkgList=[com.xxx.xxx]
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2426)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.remove(IWindowSession.java:1439)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:8153)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:8130)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:499)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:440)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5751)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5667)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:61)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5734)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2224)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7916)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:577)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1009)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.sonim.spccplatformjar.utils.Utils.checkAccessPermission(Utils.java:22)
    at com.sonim.spccplatformjar.settings.SPCCFrameworkAPI.startWindowRPSNotify(SPCCFrameworkAPI.java:669)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onWindowsVisible(ActivityRecord.java:6005)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.updateReportedVisibilityLocked(ActivityRecord.java:6101)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished(WindowStateAnimator.java:218)
```

This only happens on Sonim XP9900 and Android 12 (API-Level 31). I tried to look around about SPCC API permission but could not find anything concrete but based on my analysis:

Sonim device has `scout` app that monitors all the application running in that device. That monitoring is done by using SPCC service.

Based on the stacktrace, can some one point to any leads?

I have tried to grant extra permissions like Bluetooth and Location but still the issue persists. I tried to reach Sonim support team but no-update yet.